# Will app_offline.htm stop current requests or just new requests?

Tags: iis

Like the title says, If I place an `app_offline.htm` in the application root, will it cut off currently running requests, or just new ones?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is my lame experiment; I created an ASPX page with the following code:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    Response.Write("Step 1<br />");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Response.Write("Step 2<br />");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Response.Write("Step 3<br />");
}
```

This code simply introduces some loooong page loads.  I accessed the page and while it was loading, I created an "app_offline.htm" file.  I then loaded another web browser and confirmed the application was offline.  I then re-visited my "loading" request...it completed all the way to step 3.

This confirms that current requests finish loading and new requests are turned away.

Comment: `if you place a file with this name in the root of a web application directory, ASP.NET 2.0 will shut-down the application, unload the application domain from the server, and stop processing any new incoming requests for that application`

Answer (score 5):

From ScottGu's blog:

> Basically, if you place a file with
>   this name in the root of a web
>   application directory, **ASP.NET 2.0
>   will shut-down the application, unload
>   the application domain from the
>   server, and stop processing any new
>   incoming requests for that
>   application**.  ASP.NET will also then
>   respond to all requests for dynamic
>   pages in the application by sending
>   back the content of the
>   app_offline.htm file (for example: you
>   might want to have a “site under
>   construction” or “down for
>   maintenance” message).

[App_Offline.htm - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx)

So, it seems like it will continue processing current request, but stop new incoming requests.