# IIS Maintenance Mode ?

Tags: iis-7

I would like to take a website offline and work on it. When I set the siteEnabled parameter false it takes website maintenance mode. However, I cannot access it locally to see the issues. How can I only enable the website for localhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this I usually recommend using app_offline.htm, see:
[ASP.NET 2.0 - How to use app_offline.htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153449/asp-net-2-0-how-to-use-app-offline-htm)

Basically you can add this file to your site and if it exists then that will be served instead.