# Web app displaying app_offline.htm content even after removing it from root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I have created an `app_offline.htm` and placed it in my web app's root directory; this displayed the temporary contents of the file on the website domain whilst my app is in development.

However, when deleting the `app_offline.htm` file from the root folder of my web app and when I republish my web app, the contents of `app_offline.htm` are still displayed. I was expecting the original contents of my web application to be displayed.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have some sort of caching enabled on the server? Like an OutputCache?

An IIS restart might fix your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

JUST DELETE THE BROWSER CHACHE AND COOKIES
99% PROBLEM WILL BE SOLVED!

another way  is to
rename the root folder and come to the browser and refresh it will say "root doesn't exit" then change the root folder name to original and then come to browser and refreash

Comment: I would like to keep my cookies though. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: ok then rename the root folder and come to the browser and refresh it will say "root doesn't exit" then change the root folder name to original and then come to browser and refreash

Comment: Does not make any difference.

Comment: ok to solve the problem can u provide me with wha kind of server u r using and what type of languages u have used in your app

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server, C# ASP.NET MVC

Comment: try to restart your server if it is not work change the browser still not working clear all temp files and restart your pc hope it will help