# How to reload the page if the server is offline?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When deploying our app we use `app_offline.htm` to tell IIS to make our application unavailable. If there are any clients that have the Angular app loaded already, what I would like to do is intercept any requests to the server while the app is offline and then reload the page so that `app_offline.htm` displays instead of the Angular app.

I thought it would be as simple as putting `<!--Offline-->` or something at the top of `app_offline.htm` and then have an http interceptor that checks if any response starts with that, but I never seem to get the content of `app_offline.htm` in a response. Amazingly, I'm still getting app content in the responses. I'm wondering if maybe it's pulling a cached version of the content or something. If I manually reload the page, I do get the `app_offline.htm` page as expected.

So how can I detect if the server is unavailable and reload the page?

**UPDATE**

So this appears to maybe be more of an IIS configuration issue than anything. The `app_offline.htm` file appears to only affect resources managed by ASP.NET. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916070/64279), I learned that you can configure ASP.NET MVC to handle all requests using this following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This has the effect of preventing static content like HTML from being served even if `app_offline.htm` exists, but it also appears to continue firing the 'response' handler of the Angular http interceptor with `undefined` as the response instead of firing the 'responseError' handler with an object having a status of 503 Service Unavailable. I'm hesitant to use this solution because I don't know if there are other conditions that may cause an `undefined` response, but so far it appears to be working:

```
function appOfflineHttpInterceptor($window, $q) {
    return {
        'response': function (response) {
            if (typeof response == "undefined")
                $window.location.reload();

            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
}
```

Does anyone know if there are other conditions that would cause an undefined response - which would render this solution nonviable?

Comment: A quick solution would be, if you are using ajax calls(or equal), just check on the client side for an Error response(or a status-flag, in the response) and redirect from the client. with `window.location.href`. for a better solution, you would have to share more information. :-D

Comment: @winner_joiner, you'd think, but I'm not getting any error responses. I'm not sure why.

Comment: If no error response maybe atleast a timeout error. Or does your IIS continue serving to calls? If timeouts don't work, could you give use more information how the system works to give a better solution.(last option with little users could be pooling the server every couple of seconds, but with many users, you could kill the server)

Comment: maybe i don't get the question right, but isn't the problem coming from the fact that you want to load `app_offline.htm` when app is made unavailable? If so, the client will still have the angular app on his side, then you can't check for `<!--Offline-->` because it is in the file you want to load? or did i understand the question upside down?

Comment: @Kaddath, when you put `app_offline.htm` in the root of your site, IIS should serve that for every request instead of the actual requested content, but now I'm wondering if it only applies to ASP.NET content - which would explain why I'm still seeing my partials come through. I'm testing that now. Maybe this is an IIS configuration issue. I'm checking to see if adding `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` will force `app_offline.htm` to be served for all types of content.

Comment: @adam0101 thanks, sorry didn't want to waste your time, i'm just a curious guy that likes to undestand ^^ this looks like a IIS specific issue indeed..

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess based on what information you have given so far. Is your server serving `app_offline.htm` as a normal page. In other words is it sending a HTTP Status Code **200 OK**? If so that is why you do not see an error in your ajax calls.

You could serve the page with a **503 Service Unavailable** which would trigger error handlers in your ajax requests. Then you could conditionally handle the 503 and redirect the entire loaded app page.