# Bring all applications offline on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, app-offline.htm

I have about 68 applications running on my IIS. These applications are divided across 18 websites.

I have created an app_offline.htm for each website but it doesn't seem to be working. I think the reason is because the applications are being run are from different folders in the file system (and are not necessarily in the Website root). Many of the applications that we have are classic ASP as well.

The app pool generally set is for .NET CLR v 2.0 (only few are 'NO MANAGED CODE'). For most of the sites, the app_offline.htm is not working at all.

I have this app_offline.htm page that redirects the users to the new server, what is the best way to forward all requests (both on 80 and 8080) to one app_offline file. My IIS version is 7.5

**Clarification**

In my organization the local applications are being used with server names. Like a send e-mail application is used as (http://usap611/sendmail) or a local leave application is used as (http://usap611:8080/leave). We have a new Windows server with 2012 version of OS and have already migrated the apps. So we need to show an offline page to the people who may have these links bookmarked in their browsers and the app_offline page has the new links for the apps in there.

Comment: Can you clarify "new server" - I"m thinking adjusting `DNS` or some network level adjustment (instead of redirect).

Comment: New server is a new Windows server that we have migrated on. The 68 applications are being referred by server name directly (example http://usap119:8080/hradmin/)

Comment: Yes - the suggestion is to use DNS to point usap119 at your new server.

Comment: Yes I suggessted that @Nick.McDermaid but the managment wants the users to use the new server name (I don't know why) so anyone who uses the old server name should be served a page which says the server has migrated :-S. Can it be done?

Comment: Basically it just sounds like you just need to get `app_offline.htm` working.  If you cant get it working there are probably other solutions, including using default pages, that you can use

Comment: Here are some other things to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153449/asp-net-2-0-how-to-use-app-offline-htm