# How can I get the site state in Asp .net core with powershell after I set up app_offline.htm?

Tags: powershell, iis

Starting from this post:
[ASP.NET 2.0 - How to use app_offline.htm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153449/asp-net-2-0-how-to-use-app-offline-htm)

Using powershell to deploy the new version of the site.
Copying app_offline.htm to the site folder.
The offline page is in place.
But cannot get the state of the site.
The app (value) and the site (state) are both Started.
If I try to copy the files, some .dll is not released.
So, how can I know when the site is offline?

Comment: Since app_offline.htm is not part of IIS pipeline, it is hard to get status with IIS API directly. I think you could try to send webrequest to loop query  /app_offline.htm under all sub-applications. If it receive 200, then the site/application might be offline.

Comment: It should stop the app, right? And I can get that with powershell. The application is not down, since it display the htm. So, not sure how to get that with powershell.

Comment: publish to  site folder and put app_offline.htm won't stop the app. So it will always remain site:started. That's why I suggest you access URL /app_offline.htm and read status code instead of reading IIS properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help!