# Display downtime page when publishing application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

Is it possible in ASP.NET MVC to display a downtime page when publishing a project out to a server?
Right now, if I hit the page while I am publishing I get an error:

```
Could not load type "App.MvcApplication"
```

It would be awesome if we could setup a downtime page so that users know to come back at a later time, instead of thinking that the app is busted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an `app_offline.htm` page to your application root, traffic will be redirected to that page until you remove or rename it.

**More info**

- [Scott Gu's App_Offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx)
- [App_Offline.htm and working around the "IE Friendly Errors" feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx)
- [Will app_offline.htm stop current requests or just new requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179556/will-appoffline-htm-stop-current-requests-or-just-new-requests)

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the application automatically (without renaming or removing app_offline.htm) after deployment progress is completed? Beacuse I need to forward the request to app_offline.htm only during publish progress. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to doing this in the application is to have IIS sort this out for you.

[Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) gives this feature, and also allows you to run warm-up scripts.